# Are there any rules as to why the letter 'r' is silent in some words?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, rhoticity

How do I know when to keep *r* silent in pronunciation?

Examples:

Not silent

- cry
- free
- friend

Silent

- German
- iron
- learn

Comment: The letter *r* is not silent (in my pronunciation at least) of iron (very different to ion) or learn (very different to lean).

Comment: In the former three, the *r* follows a consonant and precedes a vowel. In the latter three, it follows a vowel, and whether or not it is pronounced **depends on the dialect**, but in any case it changes the pronunciation of the vowel, so one can argue that in a way it's always present. To make a long story short, simply memorize every single word — just like native speakers do. There is no reliable way to know the pronunciation just by looking at the spelling. See ["Hou tu pranownse Inglish"](http://www.zompist.com/spell.html), section "Vowels before r".

Comment: In the US, it's more a matter of where you are in the country, as opposed to where the *r* is in the word.  The closer you get to [Boston](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbK4cL3QSc0), the [more silent](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckt4vpulAzc) the r's become.

Comment: @J.R. Most useful point. +1 for '... where **you** are ...'

Comment: @J.R. Bostoners just move the r's to the ends of words ending in -ea, like idear and gonorrhear.

Comment: IF you ask the wrong question, you get the wrong answer. "The letter 'r'" makes **no** sound. Ever. It is written, not spoken. English spelling does not represent the sounds of English, and resonant phonemes like /r/ are inconsistently represented in spelling, and also vary a great deal in pronunciation from one person to another, and from one dialect to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In so-called non-rhotic pronunciations of English (which includes what are perceived as 'standard' British pronunciations), a written 'r' does not actually represent an 'r' sound when it is syllable-final.

On the other hand, the case of "iron" is simply a rare exception.

Comment: Wicked good answer! After I read your response, I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents) to be helpful, too.

Comment: Americans pronounce "iron" as "eye-urn" (ˈaɪərn). So it's not actually an exception to the syllable-final pronunciation rule for 'r'; it's a case where you can't tell that the 'r' is syllable-final from the spelling.

Comment: I'm not convinced ‘syllable-final’ is the best way to describe the conditioning here. ‘Not pre-vocalic’ seems more precise to me, unless you consider syllable boundaries to shift in cases like “the bar was” vs. “the bar is”. (And I think you actually mean ‘in the syllable coda’: the r in _learn_, for example, is not syllable-final, but it is in the coda.)

Comment: Hi Janus -- Sorry yes, I should probably have said "non syllable initial" rather than "syllable final". In a case such as "The bar is", in a simplistic segmental model at least, it would be usual to consider that the 'r' fills the syllable onset. (In a more detailed analysis beyond, I think, the scope of what the questioner was asking, you could argue that "it's more complex than that"...)